# How to update the display of remote hash in git log?

Tags: git, git-log

If I type `git log`, I get a list of hashes with associated info (date, committer, log message..).  If I'm on the `main` branch, and so are all my remotes, then if a remote currently has `main` at a given hash, then next to the hash it displays the remote name.  (It might be different than my local `main` because I haven't pushed my `main` to a particular remote.  In particular, if `git` is used to deploy, I may purposely have changes not yet deployed.)

I am noticing that this display is out of date since someone else pushed to a couple of the remotes.  That is, the remotes are showing on hashes that are not really true when I examine the remote via the web.

How do I update my `git log` display so I can see which hash each remote is really on?

P.S. This may be a duplicate of some other question, but I've been searching "git log remote show hash" and the like, and it brings up other topics.  Perhaps I don't know the precise terminology.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ah, I think I found the answer.

The display of where a remote is in the `git log` output is driven by git refs, and the way to update that display for a particular remote is `git fetch remote-name` for each remote I want to update.

Comment: sorta.. but not exactly..

Comment: Because the display isn't based on git refs. It's based on the actual data your working repository has.  A piece of that data is the refs.  The way in which you update the refs and the data is generally through `git fetch` or `git fetch <name of remote>`  log is simply rendering the topological branch history that your local repository has as a graph of commits.   It also overlooks that after fetch remotes will be updated (`origin/x`) not locals (`x`).  For what it's worth I didnt downvote you I only left the comment.

Comment: I see, that's somewhat helpful. I think it's okay for me to ask a question about git even if I don't fully understand git. That doesn't mean that I don't understand pieces of it, or do research. But, I go to a question-answering site because there's something I don't understand, and sometimes that means I don't know all the terminology or mechanism either.

Comment: I was referring to why your answer got downvoted... asking a question is different from answering one. I suspect people downvoted your question becuase it doesnt appear that you've done basic reading about how git works and how to use git and as such they dont find the question useful or interesting.. most folks reccomend `the git book` https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2.  Feel free to accept my answer as well if it answers your question or accept your answer if you really insist that your answer is correct

Comment: Your answer does not satisfy your own condition to update all your remotes.

Comment: Fixed to specify how to update all remotes.

Answer (score 1):

**updated to fetch all remotes and reworded**

- If you are out of date then first fetch all of your remotes by doing `git fetch --all`. OR `git fetch <remote-name>` if you only want certain remotes updated. OR `git fetch --multiple <remote-name> <another-remotename>`
- If you want to see the log of your branch do `git log`
- If you want to see the log of a remote then ask for that `git log origin/foo` or in your case `git log origin/main` that will show you the remote's log as opposed to `git log` which is implicitly converted to `git log <YOUR_BRANCH>`.

Note that after a fetch is performed (as above) the ONLY thing that will change in `git log` of your branch is possible addition of labels of the remotes of other branches which may now point to the commits in this branches history.  It will not update this branch to its potentially upstream updated state and it will not update any local version of those remote branches to point anywhere new either.

Comment: This answer is not right. First, a bare "git fetch" is not enough. Without specifying a remote, this will fetch origin, but I want to fetch all my remotes, as stated in my question. Second, I want "git log", as I specified in my question, not git log of some other remote. In fact, the display from git log of the branch I'm on is indeed updated by doing only a fetch, and not a merge. The branch itself is not updated, only the display of where the remotes are on that branch. I think that is actually git refs, although apparently you dispute that.